# How to round array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have list of probabilities in arrays. The probabilities values is like 1.4011082420205222e-06, etc. I try to round the probabilities value so that the value is more readable (for example : 0,01, etc), but get an error.

Here is my code:

```
import json_lines
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('dep_prob.jl', 'rb') as f:
    all_item = []
    for item in json_lines.reader(f):
        itemframe = pd.DataFrame(item)
        all_item.append(itemframe)

a = all_item[0]
probabilities = a['probability_table'].values 
prob = np.round(probabilities , 2)
```

And the error is: 
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code before the last line:

```
probabilities = np.asarray(probabilities)
```

Comment: Try printing a['probability_table'] , type(a), type(a['probability_table'])

Comment: the output: type(a)  --> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame; type(a['probability_table'])  --> pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: Your a['probabilities'] holds String values, try to convert it to int by using x = pd.to_numeric(a['probability']) , then round of x